# Interceptor no Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Fiz um interceptor para que toda vez que o sistema tivesse uma mensagem para exibir disparasse um javascript com a mensagem.

```
public class MessagesInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    public static final String urlBase = "http://localhost:8084";
    public static String urlToRedirect = "";
    public static String message = "";

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
        Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView)
        throws Exception {
        if(message.length() > 0){
            PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
            pw.write("<script>"
                    + "window.alert('"+message+"'); "
                    + "location.href='" + urlBase + urlToRedirect + "';"
                    + "</script>");
            pw.close();
            message = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Mas o meu problema é para qual `url` vou redirecionar.
Criei uma variável `urlToRedirect` para dizer para qual `url` vou redirecionar.
Gostaria de não ter ela e descobrir se tem alguma forma forma de pegar para onde a `action` está redirecionando sem ter que passar para uma variável dentro do interceptor.

```
@RequestMapping(Routes.basicExercisesAct)
public String runExercise(HttpServletRequest request, Model model){
    resolution = request.getParameter("resolution");
    //javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, resolution);
    exercise.buildGrading(resolution);
    if (exercise.hasCompileErrors != true) {
        //exercicio.salvarBancoDeDados(codigoUsuario, conexao);
        if (chooser.canDoNextExercise() == true) {
            MessagesInterceptor.urlToRedirect = Routes.basicExercisesNew; 
            return "redirect:"+Routes.basicExercisesNew;
        } else {
            //javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Parabéns. Você passou no teste!");
            MessagesInterceptor.urlToRedirect = Routes.main;
            return "redirect:"+Routes.main;
        }
    } else {
        //exercicio.salvarBancoErroDeCompilacao(codigoUsuario, conexao);
        if (exercise.endOfAttempts == true) {
            if (chooser.canDoNextExercise() == true) {
                /*javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Estouro de "
                        + "quantidade de tentativas atingido. "
                        + "Por favor, fazer o próximo exercício");
                     */
                MessagesInterceptor.urlToRedirect = Routes.basicExercisesNew; 
                return "redirect:"+Routes.basicExercisesNew;
            } else {
                //javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Você foi reprovado no teste");
                MessagesInterceptor.urlToRedirect = Routes.main;
                return "redirect:"+Routes.main;
            }
        }
        else {
            MessagesInterceptor.urlToRedirect = Routes.basicExercisesUpdate; 
            return "redirect:"+Routes.basicExercisesUpdate;
        }
    }

}
```

Se a pergunta não estiver clara me avisem que reformulo ela.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que não seja uma boa abordagem usar o um interceptor para fazer ações de redirect e exibir popups na tela. Em questão ao interceptor ele geralmente é um componente Application scopped então usar atributos estáticos vai gerar problemas de acesso com usuários simultâneos, onde um usuário poderá receber uma mensagem que deveria estar destinada à outro usuário.

Em relação ao seu script dentro do interceptor que tal trocá-lo por uma view com o código dentro ? Nós utilizamos uma view apenas para fazer o redirect e exibir as mensagens de sucesso:

redirect.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<p style="margin-top: 10px">
    Redirecionando...
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = '${location}';
</script>
```

No controller apenas

```
return new ModelAndView("redirect", "sua-url-para-redirecionar");
```

No fim não respondi sua pergunta mas espero ter ajudado.